# JavaScript Regex - test for sets of four non-duplicate characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use Regex to test if a certain string contains only sets of four non-duplicate characters.

For example I would like to test string

```
acbdbcaddacb
```

which would return true as it can return

- *acbd*
- *bcad*
- *dacb*

i.e. sets of four characters which have no duplicates even though the entire string does.

I have tried the following regex which does not work for example and I am not sure why:

```
/^(?:(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,2}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,1}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!\1))[a-d])+$/
```

Any solutions?
Thank you

Comment: For me `/^(?:(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,2}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,1}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!\1))[a-d])+$/.test('acbdbcaddacb')` returns true in chrome console - so this might be a problem with your code rather than with your regex.

Comment: @SebastianProske Sorry, I should have clarified that the problem is that it returns true falsely when it shouldn't for example `/^(?:(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,2}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,1}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!\1))[a-d])+$/.test('dbbc')` returns true incorrectly

Comment: That's because you always use `\1` in the lookaheads, but should be using `\2` in the second and `\3` in the third.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what strings should match the regex. For example, should 'dbbcad' return true or false, and why? Is 'dbbcad' even valid input?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Your current regex is only checking if the 2nd - 4th letters in each group match the 1st. I believe `/^(?:(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,2}\1))(?:([a-d])(?!.{0,1}\1|\2))(?:([a-d])(?!\1|\2|\3))[a-d])+$/` should work... or at least it's getting closer to correct I'm not sure if I left out some edge cases but it seems to be working for my test strings

Comment: That returns false for me in the chrome console as it should (unless I don't understand the problem)

Comment: I think it may be me that doesn't understand it. That string does contain a set of 4 unique characters. Time to ask the OP!

Comment: well if you look at the regex it starts with ^ (so the start of the string) and then ends with $ (the end of the string). if you wanted to match any chain of 4 unique characters you could just take those out. Currently it makes sure the entire string from start to finish are valid groups of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
function check(str) {
  var len = str.length; // check string length
  if (len % 4 == 0) { // pass if divided by 4 == true
    var arr = str.match(/.{4}/g); // make the in array
    var res = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].match(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])(?!.*\1))*$/)) {
        res.push(arr[i]); // push if passed regex
      }
    }
    if (arr.length === res.length) { // if they same that means true
      console.log("true");
    } else {
      console.log("false");
    }

  } else {

    console.log("false");
  }
}

var str1 = "acbdbcaddacb";
check(str1); // true
var str2 = "aabbccdd";
check(str2); // false
var str3 = "abcde";
check(str3); // false
var str4 = "abcdabcdabcdabcd";
check(str4); // true
var str5 = "abcdabcdabcdabc4";
check(str5); // false
```